# Node cpp extension threads

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, v8

everybody

Trying to write my first node extension for dynamic library ("/usr/local/lib/libkdriveExpress.so")

This extension should connect to device and receive data. On received data it should call back function from javascript. I have found how to store persistent function so it isn't issue to call js function from cpp.

In this example I use simple c++ function just to except issues with js

```
/// 
void test(const uint8_t *telegram, uint32_t telegram_len, void *user_data){
    kdrive_logger_ex(KDRIVE_LOGGER_ERROR, "kdrive: event callback");
};
void ap_open_ip(const FunctionCallbackInfo <Value> &args) {
/// ...
/// now register
    kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback(ap, &test, NULL, &key);
/// ...
}
```

when I call it from js it works fine.

```
if (kdrive.ap_open_ip(ap, "192.168.3.201") == 0) {
    console.log("great success", ap);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(kdrive.whoami());
   }, 2000)
}
```

but when I call any function from extension it doesn't work. In the code above I call whoami function and it doesn't use dynamic library, just return string.

here is the log:

```
great success 1
11:42:45:518 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:45:590 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:45:692 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:45:735 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:45:831 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:45:900 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:46:167 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
11:42:46:717 [kdrive.express] kdrive: event callback
>>> whoami call
11:42:47:525 [kdrive.connector.ConnectorNotificationHandler] onSignal: System exception: cannot lock mutex
11:42:48:067 [kdrive.connector.ConnectorNotificationHandler] onSignal: System exception: cannot lock mutex
11:42:48:420 [kdrive.connector.ConnectorNotificationHandler] onSignal: System exception: cannot lock mutex
```

Here is description for kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback function:

> Registers a callback function.
>
> This callback function will be called when a telegram is received by
>   the Access Port. A notification thread is used internally so this
>   callback will be in the context of the notification thread (and not
>   the main thread). That is, care should be taken when calling out from
>   the callback. This function generates a unique key to represent the
>   callback. This key can be used to remove the callback at a later
>   state.

So, I guess issue is with threads. 
I'm newbie with cpp extensions and cpp, writed in js before. So, I guess, I need to learn how threads in cpp works and how v8 engine handle it.

Would appreciate any advice, suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I call any function from extension it doesn't work"? Did you forget to post the code that does not work? Also getting from js to cpp may take quite a while...

Comment: Take a look at js code. At first I call kdrive.ap_open_ip(). It start to listen for event and it works fine("kdrive: event callback" in log). Then I need to call other kdrive functions. In js code I call kdrive.whoami() in setTimeout. This function returns string without any interaction with dynamic library. But if you take a look at log after this call event callback doesn't work.
>>> whoami call - we called kdrive.whoami()
11:42:47:525 [kdrive.connector.ConnectorNotificationHandler] onSignal: System exception: cannot lock mutex - now event callback doesn't work

Comment: The code snippets you posted are quite far from [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What are `kdrive` and `ap` objects? Who owns data supplied in `test` callback? Where is this callback called from? Maybe you keep some kind of `kdrive` context inside of c++ js object wrapper and when it goes out of scope and gets destroyed by js GC program stucks in inconsistent state?

Comment: Dynamic library is just a piece of data containing machine instructions, it does not call anything. If some code is executed then it means that there is some thread of execution executing the code. In your case you have at least once thread where js event loop is running. If `test` callback is called independently then it is probably running in another thread. I guess you need to figure out how to use this library without node first.

Comment: All kdrive_* functions in c++ code (kdrive_logger_ex, kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback, etc) are called from dynamic library. I do have #include <kdrive.h> at beginning of cpp file.

kdrive object in js is built extension by node-gyp:

    var kdrive = require('./build/Release/kdrive');

test callback is called by dynamic library after we register it in

    kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback(ap, &test, NULL, &key);

ap is integer value:

    var ap = kdrive.ap_create();
    kdrive.ap_open_ip(ap, "192.168.3.201")

Comment: This is c example from sdk. 

` if (kdrive_ap_open_ip(ap, "192.168.3.201") == KDRIVE_ERROR_NONE)
 {
  /* now we simply go into bus monitor mode, and display received telegrams */
  kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback(ap, &on_telegram, NULL, &key);
  kdrive_logger(KDRIVE_LOGGER_INFORMATION, "Entering BusMonitor Mode");
  kdrive_logger(KDRIVE_LOGGER_INFORMATION, "Press [Enter] to exit the application ...");
  getchar();
 kdrive_ap_close(ap);
 }`

It works fine. Also I have python example, so this is understood for me.

Thanks for notes, I will try research next.

Comment: From this example it appears to me that ap is actually a kdrive context handle which is associated with it's internal state which may be used to create threads, invoke callbacks and whatever other staff this library does. When do you call `kdrive_ap_close` in your js wrapper code? Lifetime of this object is probably messed up.

Comment: I believe library creates separate thread to receive event. From description "A notification thread is used internally so this callback will be in the context of the notification thread (and not the main thread). That is, care should be taken when calling out from the callback. ". Full description is available here: [link](http://www.weinzierl.de/doxygen/kdrive/kdriveExpress-16.1.0/c/group__kdrive__express__access.html#gad8b0f702e8d682c4063e8b9f6517a18a)

In c code kdrive_ap_close called after we press Enter and getchar(); handle it. But even if we close app by Ctrl-C it's ok on next run.

Comment: Back to threads. As I understand in c example it load library once and it works in one main thread and kdrive_ap_register_telegram_callback creates new separate from main. But it isn't clear for me how v8 works with it. What is happening when we call kdrive.whoami() from js?

Comment: I have no idea what happens when `kdrive.whoami()` is called since you haven't provided it's code. But `kdrive` js object will be referenced by `setTimeout` callback and will survive at least for two seconds and then destroyed by GC.

Comment: That's it. Added new setTimeout and it's alive between two timeouts. So, all I have to do is avoid object destroying. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't related to threads. It was because js gc destroyed kdrive object.